# jQuery.Click method reloads the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to creating a floating div who shows up when a button is triggered. It's not hard, but when i press the button the page automatically reloads. I don't know why.

I tried to use Bootstrap's Popover, but it doesn't working as expected due to this same problem. When the popover is triggered, the page reloads and the popover obviously disappear.

I'm using RoR, just saying in case that would be useful to find out the problem.

I have something like this in document's bottom:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-warning" id="example">Show</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("Page is loaded.");

        // Custom Popover
        $("#example").click(function() {
            console.log("Showing");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The first `console.log` inside ready function is shown when the page loads. When I trigger the button "Show", that `console.log` is again shown in browser's console. And that doesn't make any sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to stop the default behaviour of the link by using `preventDefault()`:

```
$("#example").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Showing");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a problem, instead of `class` you have used `href`

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-warning" id="example">Show</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, in my original html file i have the href put. I forgot to add it in the example above. That's not the problem. Sorry though.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

You're setting your classes in your `href` attribute instead of `class`

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-warning" id="example">Show</a>
```

You'll want to stop your browser from following the `href` when the link is invoked:

```
$("#example").click(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't follow href
    console.log("Showing");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to stop the anchor to do it's default function, loading the page specified its href.
This code should do the trick:

```
$("#example").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log("Showing");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can't be, it should work fine. There must be some other issue, please jsfill of your full page.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  console.log("Page is loaded.");

  // Custom Popover
  $("#example").click(function() {
      console.log("Showing");
  });
```

});

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRKd5)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a fully working example.
[test here](http://jsfiddle.net/2kcBw/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   console.log("Page is loaded.");

   $("#example").click(function(e) 
   {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("works");
   });
```

});